# how to get unique dataframes from a list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list as follows including some duplicated dataframes (there are two unique)

```
library("tibble")

dfy <- list(
  tibble(
    x=1:10,
    y=x*2
  ),
  tibble(
    x=1:10,
    y=x*2
  ),
  tibble(
    x=1:10,
    y=3*x
  ),
  tibble(
    x=1:10,
    y=x*2
  ),
  tibble(
    x=1:10,
    y=3*x
  )
)
```

I am looking for solution to get output list with only two unique dataframes from initial list.

Basic approach with vectors as list items doesn't work in this case since data frames are not allowed as vector elements:

```
x <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b = c(2,3,4), c=c(4,5,6))
unique(unlist(x))
```

I tried to create a solution using for loop, but I didnt get excepted output:

```
uni <- list()

for(x in seq_along(dfy)){
  if(x==1){
    uni[[x]] <- dfy[[x]]
  } else {
    lgl <- logical()
    for(y in seq_along(uni)){
      lgl[x] <- identical(dfy[[x]],uni[[y]])
    }
    if(all(lgl)==FALSE){
      uni[[x]] <- dfy[[x]]
    }
  }
}
```

Above method should work as follows:

1. At the beginning I initiate empty list for unique elements.
2. First element from input list i assign to this empty list.
3. Later, for each next list element from input list (with duplicates) I check if specific one exists already in uni list - if no - I get vector lgl full of FALSES so then I add this specific item from initial list to list of unique items.

Can you please provide me a hint what I did wrong doing that solution or maybe you have a ideas for sole that problem another way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Do you want `unique(dfy)`?

Comment: `unique(dfy)`, or `dfy[!duplicated(dfy)]`, these usual ways have nice methods for lists and work fine.

Comment: As for your code, you have a few issues. You should be using `lgl[y]` not `lgl[x]`. And `if(all(lgl)==FALSE)` is wrong. `lgl` (terrible name - give it a descriptive name!) is TRUE when the data frame under consideration matches one already in `uni`. `all(lgl)` will be TRUE only if the data frame under consideration matches **all** elements of `uni`. Your intent is `if(all(lgl == FALSE))`, which would be better written as `if(!any(lgl))` or `if(all(!lgl))`.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `unique`

```
unique(dfy)
```